# Read a list of files with R, each file contains a list of float numbers. what's the proper way to do it?

Tags: r

Read a list of files with R, each file contains a list of float numbers. what's the proper way to do it?

I'v never used R before. Just want to try a little bit of R

All files contains 121 float numbers, one number per line

any words will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you want to do with the data in the list of files? Greg's answer shows you one way to read a single file, which you could stick in a loop over the file names. But do you want the results in *n* R objects or combined in some manner?

For example, I have two files foo.txt and bar.txt in my working directory. I can list all `*.txt` files using `list.files()`, then operate on that list to read them in and combine them in different ways.

For example: here we combine them into a matrix:

```
flist <- list.files(pattern = ".txt$") ## so we get only files .txt not .txt~
(f <- sapply(flist, scan))
## or to a data.frame
(df <- data.frame(sapply(flist, scan)))
## fix up the colnames and rownames
colnames(f) <- colnames(df) <- paste("File", seq_along(flist), sep = "")
head(df)

  File1 File2
1    12    12
2    23    23
3    34    34
4    45    45
5     6     6
6    67    67
```

If you wanted to concatenate the files together into one long vector, then we could achieve that with

```
> do.call(c, lapply(flist, scan))
Read 10 items
Read 10 items
 [1]  12  23  34  45   6  67  78  54  34 324  12  23  34  45   6  67  78  54  34
[20] 324
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

The scan function is a very basic (but powerful) function for reading in data, you can just do something like:

```
 mydata1 <- scan('your 1st filename here')
```

and my data will be a vector with the values from the file.